# Selenium get a value of a JavaScript global variable (from Python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I would like to get a value from a global variable in JavaScript:

```js
    clearInterval(countdownTimerTHx);
    var saniye_thx = 298 // <--- This variable
    function secondPassedTHx() {
```

[image: For a larger code snippet see this]

Here I just want to get the value **"298"** in saniye_thx var

The XPATH is: **//*[@id="c2VuZE9nb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9r"]/script**

How can I do that?
Thank you, and have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a webdriver instance `driver`, you should be able to use the `execute_script` function in order to execute client-side JavaScript to get a value.

Something like the following should show enough context to call the `execute_script` function and get the value.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome()

# Setup driver to go to appropriate web site

saniye_thx = driver.execute_script('return saniye_thx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JavascriptExecutor

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

var returnValue = js.executeScript("return saniye_thx");

Comment: I think this concept would help achieve the goal, but the author is looking for a solution in Python.

Comment: That's right, I'm looking for a python solution, thanks anyway for your help.